# How to remove double quotes from my output value so that it can be passed in another api request?

Tags: regex, api, jmeter

I have written a regular expression for fetching a value from response data in jmeter, now I want to use it in another api as request but the value I am getting is in double quotes so if I am sending request I am getting
I want to send this "1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07" value which I am getting from regular expression extractor to be without quotes so that it can be sent to another request.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 73: https://processing_dev.cazcreekdev.com/mailmerge/getprogress?mailmergeId="1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07"
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2936)
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3107)
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3195)
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3137)
at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
at java.base/java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:1048)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:535)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Where is your request response sample? Share the regex you have used in the extractor. You need to surround your regular expression with quotation.

Answer (score 0):

**i 'm not a java dev but i think is

```
str='"1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07"';
str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote('"'), "");
```

or

```
str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote('"1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07"'), '1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07');
```

Comment: But in jmeter how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your regular expression extractor configuration is not correct, it should be  possible to remove the quotes on [regex level](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

However if removing quotation marks from a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is your strict requirement you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
def before = vars.get('foo')
log.info('Before: ' + before)
def after = before.replaceAll('\"', '')
log.info('After: ' + after)
vars.put('foo', after)
```

Replace `foo` with JMeter Variable reference name you're using in your Regular Expression Extractor and it should do the trick for you.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)